# Increase listing by 5 and 10 %

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am trying to increase all of the listing prices by 5% for all listings under $500,000 and 10% for all listings $500,000 and higher. Update the listings table with the new prices.

Code base runs, but does not produce output.  Not sure whats wrong with it.

```sql
UPDATE
  listings
SET
  listing_price = listing_price + case
    when LISTING_PRICE < 500000 then (LISTING_PRICE5) / 100
    else 0
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
update listings
set listing_price = listing_price * case
    when listing_price < 500000 
        then 1.05
        else 1.10
    end
```

Comment: Yea that runs also, but it is not producing an output  (table)

Comment: @stickerbush1970: this is an `update` statement, hence it does not return anything: it modifies the data in the existing table. You can see the results afterwards with a `select` statement, like: `select listing_price from listings`.

Comment: @ GMB: Thank you for the clarification, did not know that